# how to use Adb with Alcatel Touch?

Tags: android, alcatel-ot

I have a new tablet Alcatel OneTouchEVo. I have some problem to use adb. I am using ubuntu , I  checked the Adb debug. when i use adb devices i have no devices. so i checked lsusb in order to change the android rules.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
 Bus 003 Device 081: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 097: ID 2207:0010  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5165 IMC Networks
```

So i added  to my Android rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="2207", ATTR{idProduct}=="0010", MODE="0666"
```

then the `chmod` but I have the SOme problem. their is no devices if i execute `adb devices`.

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove ATTR{idProduct}=="0010" at all